# Dependecy Injection works with Unity but doesn't with Ninject

Tags: entity-framework, dependency-injection, ninject, unity-container, unit-of-work

I've been working on EF Repository pattern with Unit of Work and DI. I was following this example: [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/547016/Code-First-Approach-using-Entity-Framework-4-1-Inv) In example is used Unity as DI container, but I want to use Ninject. 
(Note: with Unity everything works just fine).
So I've set up my Ninject Controller Factory like this: [link](http://pastebin.com/HELcW5cb).
When i go to my controller and try to list messages, it works fine but when i try to create message nothing happens, values are passed to controller and to repository, but data isn't saved to database for some reason.
Here is controller constructor:

```
 private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
    private readonly IMessageThreadRepository _messageThreadRepository;

    public TetsController(IMessageThreadRepository messageThreadRepository, IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        _messageThreadRepository = messageThreadRepository;
        _userRepository = userRepository;
    }
```

And here is code for messageThreadRepository which is being called by controller

```
 public class MessageThreadRepository : RepositoryBase<MessageThread>, IMessageThreadRepository
{
    private readonly RepositoryBase<MessageThread> _messageThreadRepository;
    private readonly RepositoryBase<Message> _messageRepository; 
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly UserRepository _userRepository;

    public MessageThreadRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, RepositoryBase<MessageThread> messageThreadRepository,
                                   IDatabaseContextFactory databaseContextFactory, UserRepository userRepository, RepositoryBase<Message> messageRepository)
        : base(databaseContextFactory)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _messageThreadRepository = messageThreadRepository;
        _userRepository = userRepository;
        _messageRepository = messageRepository;
    }
 //some code here
 // part with adding to database
  Message message = messageFactory.CreateMessage(messageBody, userSender, messageThread);

        _messageRepository.Add(message);

        if (!doesThreadExist)
        {
            _messageThreadRepository.Add(messageThread);
        }

        _unitOfWork.Commit();
}
```

**EDIT**
I've tried to add User to database, but with no luck. Again I manage to fetch all users but I can't add them, here is User repository:

```
public class UserRepository : RepositoryBase<User>, IUserRepository
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly RepositoryBase<User> _repository; 

    public UserRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IDatabaseContextFactory databaseContextFactory, RepositoryBase<User> repository) : base (databaseContextFactory)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public User GetUserById(int id)
    {
        return _repository.GetSingleByCriteria(u => u.UserId.Equals(id));
    }

    public User GetUserByEmail(string email)
    {
        return _repository.GetSingleByCriteria(u => u.Email.Equals(email));
    }

    public User GetUserByUserName(string name)
    {
        return _repository.GetSingleByCriteria(u => u.UserName.Equals(name));
    }

    public void AddUser(User user)
    {
        _repository.Add(user);
        _unitOfWork.Commit();
    }

    public IEnumerable<User> GetAllUsers()
    {
        return _repository.GetAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using MVC since you reference an article about using it with MVC.

Did you do all the steps mentioned here?

http://bubblogging.wordpress.com/2012/06/04/mvc-controller-factory-ninject/

Why are you using a custom controller factory instead of using the built-in dependency injection support of MVC, using Ninject.MVC3 package?

Comment: Yes I'm using it with MVC, and I've done all steps mentioned there, And i am not using custom controller factory, I'm using Ninject.MVC3 package, I don't believe problem is with controller, as controller gets all the data, shows data. I believe Ninject has problem with my repository.

Comment: @hyperN - since you didn't include your Ninject configuration code, we can only guess.  But it looks like you are probably creating two DbContexts, on in repository and one in UnitOfWork.  You add the user to the repository, but call the SaveChanges on the UnitOfWork, so nothing gets saved because there's nothing in the UoW context.

Comment: @hyperN - Also, why do you say you aren't using a controller factory when you say you are in your question?

Comment: That doesn't look like the Bootstrapper than comes with Ninject.MVC4 package that usually comes up in the App_Start folder.